# Android Sqlite: Delete first n records in a table (is deleting all rows instead)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using the following sql statement to delete the first 5 rows in my table:

```
DELETE FROM tblname WHERE `id`   IN (SELECT `id`   FROM tblname ORDER BY `id`   ASC LIMIT 5)
```

Instead of deleting 5 rows it deletes all of the rows.

I have also tried the following variant:

```
DELETE FROM tblname WHERE 'rowid' IN (SELECT 'rowid' FROM tblname ORDER BY 'rowid' ASC LIMIT ?)
```

I can't find any errors being generated by this. Here is the specific code I am using to perform this operation:

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
final String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE '_id' IN (SELECT '_id' FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY '_id' ASC LIMIT 5)";

final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.close();
```

Any pointers would be be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that '_id' should be in single quotes? In general, you don't put quotes around column names. I made a table with an integer  primary key field called `id` and this query works as expected:

`DELETE FROM tblname WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tblname ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)`

But this query deleted everything:

`DELETE FROM tblname WHERE 'id' IN (SELECT 'id' FROM tblname ORDER BY 'id' ASC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Thanks. This was the issue. Removed the single quotes and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `'_id'` is a constant string literal (and not a column name) on both, main query and subquery - so all records match and all records are deleted.

[Here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) is sqlite relevant documentation. Using `_id` as a column name (identifier) does not need any type of surrounding quotes, but in case you want to add some, use double quote `"`.